# Spark Dataset select with typedcolumn

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Looking at the `select()` function on the spark DataSet there are various generated function signatures:

```
(c1: TypedColumn[MyClass, U1],c2: TypedColumn[MyClass, U2] ....)
```

This seems to hint that I should be able to reference the members of MyClass directly and be type safe, but I'm not sure how...

`ds.select("member")` of course works .. seems like `ds.select(_.member)` might also work somehow?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the Scala DSL for `select`, there are many ways to identify a `Column`:

- From a symbol: `'name`
- From a string: `$"name"` or `col(name)`
- From an expression: `expr("nvl(name, 'unknown') as renamed")`

To get a `TypedColumn` from `Column` you simply use `myCol.as[T]`.

For example: `ds.select(col("name").as[String])`

Comment: this answer is correct, however be aware that this as[T] is not type safe so it could explode in RT if assuming the wrong type.

Comment: Good point. For the most help from the compiler, you have to switch to Scala types entirely, e.g., `ds.as[T].map { t: T => ... }`. Note that there will be a data conversion cost as internally Spark uses raw binary data and not Scala types.

Answer (score 21):

If you want the equivalent of `ds.select(_.member)` just use `map`:

```
case class MyClass(member: MyMember, foo: A, bar: B)
val ds: DataSet[MyClass] = ???
val members: DataSet[MyMember] = ds.map(_.member)
```

**Edit**: The argument for not using `map`.

A more performant way of doing the same would be through a projection, and not use `map` at all. You lose the compile-time type checking, but in exchange give the Catalyst query engine a chance to do something more optimized. As @Sim alludes to in his comment below, the primary optimization centers around not requiring whole contents of `MyClass` to be deserialized from Tungsten memory space into JVM heap memory--just to call the accessor--and then serialize the result of `_.member` back into Tungsten.

To make a more concrete example, let's redefine our data model like this:

```
  // Make sure these are not nested classes 
  // (i.e. in a top level compilation units).
  case class MyMember(something: Double)
  case class MyClass(member: MyMember, foo: Int, bar: String)
```

These need to be `case` classes so that `SQLImplicits.newProductEncoder[T <: Product]` can provide us with an implicit `Encoder[MyClass]`, required by the `Dataset[T]` API.

Now we can make the example above more concrete:

```
  val ds: Dataset[MyClass] = Seq(MyClass(MyMember(1.0), 2, "three")).toDS()
  val membersMapped: Dataset[Double] = ds.map(_.member.something)
```

To see what's going on behind the scenes we use the `explain()` method:

```
membersMapped.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) SerializeFromObject [input[0, double, false] AS value#19]
+- *(1) MapElements <function1>, obj#18: double
   +- *(1) DeserializeToObject newInstance(class MyClass), obj#17: MyClass
      +- LocalTableScan [member#12, foo#13, bar#14]
```

This makes the serialization to/from Tungsten explicitly evident.

Let's get to the same value using a projection[^1]:

```
val ds2: Dataset[Double] = ds.select($"member.something".as[Double])
ds2.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [something#25]
```

That's it! A single step[^2]. No serialization other than the encoding of `MyClass` into the original Dataset.

[^1]: The reason the projection is defined as `$"member.something"` rather than `$"value.member.something"` has to do with Catalyst automatically projecting the members of a single column DataFrame.

[^2]: To be fair, the `*` next to the steps in the first physical plan indicate they will be implemented by a `WholeStageCodegenExec` whereby those steps become a single, on-the-fly compiled JVM function that has its own set of runtime optimizations applied to it. So in practice you'd have to empirically test the performance to really assess the benefits to each approach.

Comment: Note that there will be a data conversion cost as internally Spark uses raw binary data and not Scala types.

Comment: What is advantage of using Dataset in this case? Is it just trading-off type-safety over performance? I quite doesn't get when Dataset is going to be useful!

Comment: Most of the time you will just want to use a Dataframe. Sometimes, for interoperability with other functions you may want to go into DataSet space to be able to call `map`, `flatMap`, etc. without creating a UDF. Or some other side-case.