# How does spark interprets type of a column in reduce

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fold, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following table

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States       Romania             15
United States       Croatia             1
United States       Ireland             344
Egypt               United States       15
```

The table is represented as a Dataset.

```
scala> dataDS
res187: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[FlightData] = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

The schema of `dataDS` is

```
scala> dataDS.printSchema;
root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
```

I want to sum all the values of the `count` column. I suppose I can do it using the `reduce` method of `Dataset`.

I thought I could do the following but got error

```
scala> (dataDS.select(col("count"))).reduce((acc,n)=>acc+n);
<console>:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row
 required: String
       (dataDS.select(col("count"))).reduce((acc,n)=>acc+n);
                                                         ^
```

To make the code work, I had to explicitly specify that `count` is `Int` even though in the schema, it is an `Int`

```
scala> (dataDS.select(col("count").as[Int])).reduce((acc,n)=>acc+n);
```

Why did I have to explicitly specify type of `count`? Why Scala's `type inference` didn't work? In fact, the schema of the intermediate `Dataset` also infers `count` as a `Int`.

```
dataDS.select(col("count")).printSchema;
root
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that it's nullable. So, int[nullable] is not the same as int and that makes sense as it's not clear how to sum int with null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the types or look at the compiler messages.

- You start with `Dataset[FlightData]`.
- You call it's `select` with `col("count")` as an argument. `col(_)` returns `Column`
- [The only variant](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@select(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) of `Dataset.select` which takes `Column` returns `DataFrame` [which is an alias for `Dataset[Row]`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.package@DataFrame=org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]).
- There are two variants of `Dataset.reduce` one taking `ReduceFunction[T]` and the second `(T, T) => T`, where `T` is type constructor parameter of the `Dataset`, i.e. `Dataset[T]`. `(acc,n)=>acc+n` function is a Scala anonymous function, hence the second version apply.
- Expanded:

  ```scala
  (dataDS.select(col("count")): Dataset[Row]).reduce((acc: Row, n: Row) => acc + n): Row
  ```

  which sets constraints - function takes `Row` and `Row` and returns `Row`.
- `Row` has no `+` method, so the only option to satisfy

  ```scala
  (acc: ???, n: Row) => acc + n)
  ```

  is to use `String` (you can `+` `Any` to `String`.

  However this doesn't satisfy the complete expression - hence the error.
- You've already figured out that you can use

  ```scala
  dataDS.select(col("count").as[Int]).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
  ```

  where `col("count").as[Int]` is a `TypedColumn[Row, Int]` and [corresponding](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@select[U1](c1:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[T,U1]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U1]) `select` returns `Dataset[Int]`.

  Similarly you could

  ```scala
  dataDS.select(col("count")).as[Int].reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
  ```

  and

  ```scala
  dataDS.toDF.map(_.getAs[Int]("count")).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
  ```

  In all cases

  ```scala
  .reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
  ```

  being `(Int, Int) => Int`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to do it in another way. I will assume FlightData is case class with the above schema. So, the solution is using the map and reduce as below

```
val totalSum = dataDS.map(_.count).reduce(_+_) //this line replace the above error as col("count") can't be selected.
```

**Updated**: The issue of inference is not related to the dataset, Actually, when you use select you will work on Dataframe(same if you join) which is not statically typed schema and you will lose the feature of your case class. For example, the type of select will be Dataframe not Dataset so, you will not be able to infer the type.

```
val x: DataFrame = dataDS.select('count)
val x: Dataset[Int] = dataDS.map(_.count)
```

Also, from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642694/2516356) To get a `TypedColumn` from Column you simply use `myCol.as[T]`.

I did a simple example to reproduce the code and the data.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object EntryMainPoint extends App {

  //val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("SparkSessionZipsExample")
    //.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
    .getOrCreate()

  val someData = Seq(
    Row("United States", "Romania", 15),
    Row("United States", "Croatia", 1),
    Row("United States", "Ireland", 344),
    Row("Egypt", "United States", 15)
  )


  val flightDataSchema = List(
    StructField("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
    StructField("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", StringType, true),
    StructField("count", IntegerType, true)
  )

  case class FlightData(DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: String, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: String, count: Int)
  import spark.implicits._

  val dataDS = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
    StructType(flightDataSchema)
  ).as[FlightData]

  val totalSum = dataDS.map(_.count).reduce(_+_) //this line replace the above error as col("count") can't be selected.
  println("totalSum = " + totalSum)


  dataDS.printSchema()
  dataDS.show()


}
```

Output below

```
totalSum = 375

root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: integer (nullable = true)

+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
|DEST_COUNTRY_NAME|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME|count|
+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
|    United States|            Romania|   15|
|    United States|            Croatia|    1|
|    United States|            Ireland|  344|
|            Egypt|      United States|   15|
+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
```

Note: You can do a selection from the dataset using the below way

```
val countColumn = dataDS.select('count) //or map(_.count)
```

You can also have a look in this [reduceByKey in Spark Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38805673/2516356)

Comment: You can also have a look on the implementation https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala